# are format "positional parameters" of printf(3) considered ansi C?

Tags: c, settings, ansi-c

I am taking a C programing class and one of my assignments did not compile properly with my professors compiler.

My professor ended up giving me full credit after I explained my code to her, but requested that I use ansi C only. Hence my question.

here is the code I used.

```
    printf("The value of 2(%1$.1f)**3+3(%1$.1f)**2+4(%1$.1f) + 5 = %2$.1f\
     \n", y, x);
```

here is my compiler settings using xcode 4.5 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUVjg.jpg

is this ansi C? or not? and if not how would I change it to be strict ansi C?

and also here is the bit about positional parameters from apples printf(3) man page.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/printf.3.html

"

```
    Arguments are numbered starting at 1.
      If unaccessed arguments in the format string
     are interspersed with ones that are accessed the results will be indeterminate.
```

"

Comment: See the POSIX standard description of [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) and its relatives, where the `n$` notation is clearly marked as an extension over the C standard.  Also, at some point you should check whether your professor means C89 (the original ANSI C, the basis for ISO C90) or whether C99 or C2011 is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not ANSI C, not even C99. It's a POSIX extension. ANSI C does not provide any method for changing the order of the arguments to be printed. In your specific case, you'll need to pass the arguments multiple times:

```
printf("The value of 2(%.1f)**3+3(%.1f)**2+4(%.1f) + 5 = %.1f\n", y, y, y, x);
```

Comment: @H2C03 is there a way to make xcode complain if I am using a POSIX extension?

Comment: @user1787331 Xcode knows nothing about this. Do you mean *the compiler?*

Comment: @H2C03 well setup xcode (compiler settings or not ) to give me feedback when I am not using strict ansi code.

Comment: @user1787331 You can use `-Wall -std=c89 -ansi -pedantic` :)